# Are generic type aliases possible in TypeScript?

Tags: generics, typescript, alias

TypeScript 1.4 [introduced type aliases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx). The examples show how to use aliases like `type MyGreeter = Greeter<string>` but is it possible to have generic aliases?

The following examples do **not work**:

```
type GenericAlias<T> = OriginalType<T>
type GenericAlias = OriginalType<T>
```

Is it at all possible to alias generic types without typecasting them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of TypeScript 1.6 this is now possible.

```
// from #1616:
type Lazy<T> = T | (() => T);

var s: Lazy<string>;
s = "eager";
s = () => "lazy";
```

---

**Pre-1.6 answer**

No, not yet. You can see developments on this in [issue #1616](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1616).

As for when this feature will be available...

> Lately we've been quite busy with ES6 alignment and the recently announced Angular 2.0 related features. We will get to (re)evaluating some of these type system specific issues but there's no concrete date for issues like this at the moment. - [Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1616#issuecomment-77970135)

Comment: Currently in `master` branch, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3397.

Comment: @TN. cool. I'll keep an eye out for when it's released and try to remember to update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx), generic type aliases are now possible starting with TypeScript 1.6.